# Unable to mount from a Mac OS X using sshfs

Tags: mount, macos

I have SSHDroid running on the Android. I'm trying to mount it from a Mac using Fuse for OS X. I can SSH, but I am unable to SSHFS.

When I try to sshfs, I get the following error

"mount_osxfusefs: failed to mount /mount@/dev/osxfuse2: Operation not supported on socket"

Has anyone seen this?

---

Update: Not sure whether this is important. I'm trying to sshfs over wifi.

---

Android OS: Froyo 2.2
Mac OS X: 10.7.3

Comment: Have you tried it with a dedicated SSH file explorer (I don't know any for OSX off the top of my head)?

Comment: "I'm trying to mount it" makes it sound like you're trying to mount the device storage, but the error sounds like it's the Mac storage.  Can you clarify?

Comment: @Erik. No. Since Finder serves all the explorer kind of purpose, I was just trying to find how to mount the device.

Comment: @MatthewRead. This is what I see. I can ssh but not sshfs.   `~> ssh root@191.168.1.5 -p 2222
root@191.168.1.5's password: 
~/data/berserker.android.apps.sshdroid/home $ ls -d /mnt/sdcard 
/mnt/sdcard 
$exit
Connection to 191.168.1.5 closed.
~> sshfs root@191.168.1.5:/ /mount -p 2222
root@191.168.1.5's password: 
~> mount_osxfusefs: failed to mount /mount@/dev/osxfuse1: Operation not supported on socket
~> `

Comment: @iobelix I primarily asked because knowing whether accessing without sshfs works or not might bring some insight into the issue.

Comment: @Erik. I Understand. So I tried it with Fugu SSH and I was able to browse securely.

Answer (score 3):

There's a [bug](https://github.com/osxfuse/sshfs/issues/8) that prevents the OSXFuse implementation of `sshfs` from working with many versions of `sshd`, including the one used by `dropbear`, which is the implementation used by most SSH server apps for Android, including SSHDroid.

My solution to this problem was just to use a different SSH server app which runs the openssh `sshd` instead of `dropbear`.  [SSHelper](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arachnoid.sshelper) is expressly designed to do this, but I prefer to start up the full-ish linux environment provided by [Termux](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=termux&so=1&c=apps) and then run `sshd` from that command line.  This has the miraculous side effect of providing a fancy linuxy environment when you `ssh` in to your phone.

For Termux and possibly also SSHelper, you will need to edit the `sshd_config` text file if you want to change certain options.  SSHelper's config file lives at `/data/data/com.arachnoid.sshelper/etc/sshd_config`; Termux's is at `/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/etc`.  You'll also have to add your public key to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` if you want to use public key, rather than password, authentication when you log in.  The config file is the same as for `openssh` under Linux so [that documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config) applies, more or less.

Also for Termux you'll have to `apt install openssh` in order to run `sshd`.